# NullPointerException when trying to set an element in a multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having a hard time figuring how to add objects to an ArrayList of ArrayList.

When I try:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<A>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<A>>();

matrix.add(new ArrayList<A>());
matrix.add(new ArrayList<A>());
matrix.add(new ArrayList<A>());

matrix.get(0).set(0, A);
```

I get a NullPointerException.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't believe you get an NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting at position not present in arraylist, may be you need "add".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class A{}

public class arrlst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<A>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<A>>();

        matrix.add(new ArrayList<A>());
        matrix.add(new ArrayList<A>());
        matrix.add(new ArrayList<A>());

        /*matrix.get(0).set(1, new A());*/
        matrix.get(0).add(new A());

    }

}
```

Also you need to create object of class A, you can't set A.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. And that is because after `matrix.add(new ArrayList<A>());` newly added ArrayList's Size is 0.
set method initially check the size of the AraayList before setting the element at the mentioned position.

`public E set(int paramInt, E paramE) {
        RangeCheck(paramInt);
        Object localObject = this.elementData[paramInt];
        this.elementData[paramInt] = paramE;
        return localObject;
    }`

`private void RangeCheck(int paramInt) {
        if (paramInt < this.size)
            return;
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + paramInt + ", Size: "
                + this.size);
    }`

As newly added ArrayList has Size as 0, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.

So, before setting the element make sure you the elements to the ArrayList using add method.